# Angular - detecting the source trigger of digest cycle

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have an html with ui-grid. I have noticed that with the grid I have 7 digest cycles per second. I want to find what trigger this cycles. When I have replaced the grid with regular table, the cycles disappeared. What is the best way to find out?

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-performance-large-applications

Comment: do you bind a grid property to a scope function somewhere?

Comment: no function bind, only data source, and several plugins for resizeing, which i have removed to test if they are the source

Comment: havent tried alot - as I am finding where to start